# Is my sentence correct and does it make sense?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

Please help me out here, which one is correct (and makes sense).

1. **A man climbing nearby saw the accident.**
2. **A man climbing nearby met with an accident.**

Does the first sentence mean that the man who saw accident was climibing nearby or did he meet with accident like in the second sentence.

I'm confused what "saw" actually means?

Comment: Do you understand the meanings of the English verbs _**see**_ and _**meet (with)**_? All English language dictionaries provide their definitions. Please **[edit]** your question and tell us what did you not understand about the definitions of these verbs.

Comment: I m asking both sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: If you do not understand what the English verb _see_ means, it will not benefit you if we merely tell you whether or not the two sentences have the same meaning. What does the English verb _see_ mean? What does the English verb _meet_ mean? What does the English _phrasal verb_ "meet with"  mean? Their definitions are provided in any English dictionary, and if you had consulted such a dictionary, you would be able to answer the question yourself.

Comment: thanks for updating, I m sure I m not able to ask what I wanted to ask :p. I just wanted to ask the meaning of "saw" in the first sentence. rest I will check dictionary in between :)

Comment: @P.E.Dant 's argument is very true. However, it seems that you are new on the ell. The questions on the ell must show a level of effort from the OP. In other words, the very basic questions or the ones that do not show the OP's research is not appreciated. It's always a pleasure to have OP's opinion and I think you should add why you think yourself and what research you have done when asking which-one-is-correct-questions.

Comment: The meaning of saw is similar as in "a man saw an accident"; the ing part is a further description for the man's status.

Comment: @Cardinal- yes I m new on the ell.I will post questions with my opinion too in future.thanks for updating and guiding

Comment: @Cardinal Thank you for the explanation to the questioner. If the dictionary doesn't provide a useful definition (which is often the case!) there are many folks here who want to help. That's why we are here; it's certainly not for the money!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence means that a man was climbing and witnessed an accident.  The man climbing was not in an accident himself.

The second sentence means that a man was climbing and had an accident.